# MP26029 Battery Charging IC OTP issue

Tags: battery-charging

I am working on this battery charging IC MP26029, it has OTP Funtion (One Time Programmable). But i do not know how to program this IC, as there are no Uart or I2C pins available. Does any one know how to program it. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood of a quick glance at the datasheet, seems that it's programmed at the factory and you'd have to contact the manufacturer.

[image]